# Names array contains duplicates: extends FormType Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have a form that I get from a bundle, but I need to add two extra fields. I am trying to extend the formType of the bundle but I get the following error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
> ("Unable to render the form because the block names array contains
> duplicates: "_order_errors", "order_errors", "order_errors",
> "form_errors".").

```
   class OrderType extends AbstractType
    {
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
            $builder->add(
                'token_id',
                HiddenType::class,
                [
                    'required' => false,
                ]
            );
        }
    
        public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
        {
            $resolver->setDefaults([
                'inherit_data' => false,
                'validation_groups' => false,
            ]);
        }
    
        public function getParent()
        {
            return FormOrderType::class;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it by changing the formtype name to a different one than the bundle name.